# Foundation 5 and contenteditable (mobile) not working

Tags: javascript, css, html, zurb-foundation

I am working on a website that has the functionality html5 "contenteditable" instead of input fields.
Using a mobile device you can not change the fields "contenteditable", to be precise it does not appear the virtual keyboard. I tried to understand what was the cause of this problem until I commented out the line of code that calls  foundation-min.js and the fields have started to work.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from this: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3607

You need to disable the FastClick library and that should fix the issue.